# Private Ethereum Blockchain losing data

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, smartcontracts, private

I have set up a private Ethereum network where I have set the block creation time to 0 seconds because I don't want to fill empty blocks unless there is a request for a block. I have also integrated the genesis.json file. Additionally, I have developed a DApp that connects to the blockchain and stores data for a product in a Smart Contract I have created.

My issue is as follows: Sometimes (possibly due to power outages), my blockchain resets to block number 1, even though there were previous blocks. Why does this happen? Furthermore, when this occurs, my Smart Contract stops functioning

I have to perform a 'migrate --reset,' which results in the loss of all my data. Why does this happen? What do you suggest?

Additionally, do you know if there is a way to keep a backup of this data so that I can restore it in case of such an event?